# fit_transform(tfidf, lsa) returns an error

Tags: r

Whenever I run the following code:

```
lsa = LSA$new(n_topics = 100)
dtm_tfidf_lsa = fit_transform(dtm_tfidf, lsa)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in (x %*% svd_current[[singular_vectors]]) %*% diag((svd_current$d/(svd_current$d +  : 
  Matrices are not conformable for multiplication
```

I have a functional input matrix (S4 [17 x 2725]), but I still keep receiving the error above. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue! Came to the conclusion that you cannot have a larger number of topics than rows in your input matrix

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).